# XSLT: how to concatenate value in three xml elements into a fourth element on same level, and keep the other elements

Tags: xml, xslt

Have this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<root xmlns="http://www.edocu.com">
    <page1>
        <eDocuID>5a0b6b78</eDocuID>
        <FormID>Test form</FormID>
    </page1>
    <page2>
        <person>
            <ssno>12345</ssno>
        </person>
        <address>
            <ssno1>12345</ssno1>
            <address_Street>Castle</address_Street>
            <address_Number>22</address_Number>
            <address_Letter>B</address_Letter>
            <address_PostNo>1435</address_PostNo>
        </address>
    </page2>
</root>
```

Use this XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:edocu="http://www.edocu.com">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" />
    <xsl:variable name="schemaId" select="//edocu:eDocuID" />
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="http://www.asdf.no/eDocu/{$schemaId}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="//edocu:address">
        <xsl:variable name="aaa" select="//edocu:address_Street"/>
        <xsl:variable name="bbb" select="//edocu:address_Number"/>
        <xsl:variable name="ccc" select="//edocu:address_Letter"/>
        <xsl:element name="new_element">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat($aaa,$bbb,$ccc)"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<root xmlns="http://www.asdf.no/eDocu/5a0b6b78">
    <page1>
        <eDocuID>5a0b6b78</eDocuID>
        <FormID>Test form</FormID>
    </page1>
    <page2>
        <person>
            <ssno>12345</ssno>
        </person>
        <new_element xmlns="">Castle22B</new_element>
    </page2>
</root>
```

What I try to do to is concatenate three elements, address_Street, address_Number, and address_Letter into a fourth element, new_element. That works fine, but my questions is:

1. all the other elements on the same level, and the address element, disappear. How to avoid that?
2. there is an empty attribute xmlns="" on new_element. How to remove it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:edocu="http://www.edocu.com"
exclude-result-prefixes="edocu">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:variable name="new-namespace" select="concat('http://www.asdf.no/eDocu/', //edocu:eDocuID)"/>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="{$new-namespace}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="edocu:address">
    <xsl:element name="address" namespace="{$new-namespace}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <xsl:element name="new_element" namespace="{$new-namespace}">
            <xsl:value-of select="edocu:address_Street"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="edocu:address_Number"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="edocu:address_Letter"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks, question 1 ok.
How to remove the attribute in question 2?

Comment: @Batar A namespace declaration is not an attribute. And since I have placed the new element in the same namespace as its parent, there will be no empty namespace declaration on it - see: http://xsltransform.net/3MP2uBA

Comment: But I want the element to be <new_element>, not <new_element xmlns:edocu="http://www.edocu.com">. Is that possible?

Comment: @Batar Which XSLT processor are you using? (Note that adding `xmlns:edocu="edocu.com"` is redundant, but harmless - it makes no semantic difference to the output).

Comment: And also the namespace on root is gone:
xmlns="http://www.asdf.no/eDocu/5a0b6b78"

Comment: I use the built in XSLT processor in Visual Studio Pro 2015.

Comment: I am afraid I don't know what you're referring to. There is no such namespace in your input example. And I am not able to reproduce the "problem" you have reported earlier. Please try and make this more productive, the amount of time I can spend on this is limited.

Comment: Running the same test with [MSXSLCompiledTransform](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ncdD7kT) and [MSXML6](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ncdD7kT/1) shows no such problems.

Comment: See my result xml, root element, the namespace is xmlns="http://www.asdf.no/eDocu/5a0b6b78".

Comment: Oh, you want to **change** the default namespace? I am sorry, I didn't see that. Why didn't you say anything about that in your question? That's not a trivial thing - it is the equivalent of renaming all the elements in the input. I will edit my answer in a short while.

Comment: @Batar Try it now.